# Start Apache on Windows10 subsytem on startup

Tags: windows, debian

I have set up Apache2 on Debian for Windows 10 Linux subsystem, but I would like to start on Windows startup.

I have already made the startup script on `/etc/init.d` but it doesn't start with Windows startup.

Can it be made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I already found myself the answer: https://dev.to/ironfroggy/wsl-tips-starting-linux-background-services-on-windows-login-3o98

Basically set up an `.sh` file that launches Apache, then on Windows set up a programmed task that runs on startup and calls `bash.exe` with a parameter pointing to the `.sh`

Thanks anyway :)